# Do the MySQL GREATEST() and LEAST() functions work with dates?

Tags: mysql

I'm working with dates in MySQL and was wondering if I could use the GREATEST() and LEAST() functions. A quick Google didn't turn up an obvious answer, so I'm turning to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Would it be so hard to `SELECT GREATEST(DATE('2015-03-01'),DATE('2014-03-01')), LEAST(DATE('2015-03-02'),DATE('2014-03-02'))` ?

Answer (score 4):

Yes!

```
mysql> SELECT start_date, end_date, GREATEST(start_date, end_date) FROM budgets LIMIT 1;
+------------+------------+--------------------------------+
| start_date | end_date   | GREATEST(start_date, end_date) |
+------------+------------+--------------------------------+
| 2015-08-01 | 2016-08-31 |                     2016-08-31 |
+------------+------------+--------------------------------+

mysql> SELECT start_date, end_date, LEAST(start_date, end_date) FROM budgets LIMIT 1;
+------------+------------+-----------------------------+
| start_date | end_date   | LEAST(start_date, end_date) |
+------------+------------+-----------------------------+
| 2015-08-01 | 2016-08-31 |                  2015-08-01 |
+------------+------------+-----------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Bear in mind that:

```
GREATEST(date1, date2)
# Will NOT work if either is NULL


GREATEST(COALESCE(date1, 0), COALESCE(date2, 0))
# Will work
```